# WCF routing + SSL

Tags: wcf, wcf-routing

I need to create a "routing" service.
I'm trying to used the System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter of .Net
I can make it work only in HTTP mode, not in HTTPS.
The error is "Cannot establish secure SSL/TLS connection"... I also tried a custom certificate validator but it is not called! (it is created, but the validate method is not called)

I post my configuration here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
    <bindings>

        <customBinding>
            <!-- Security Off version-->
            <binding name="customBindingNotSecure">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10"/>
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>

            <!-- Security On -->
            <binding name="customBindingSecure">

                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10">
                </textMessageEncoding>
                <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
                <httpsTransport  />
            </binding>

            <binding name="platoneBinding">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />
                <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" maxBufferPoolSize="1000000" maxBufferSize="1000000" />
            </binding>

        </customBinding>


    </bindings>

    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="routingService" name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService">
            <endpoint address=""
              binding="customBinding"
              name="reqReplyEndpoint"
              contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter"  bindingConfiguration="customBindingSecure"/>

            <endpoint address=""
              binding="customBinding"
              name="reqReplyEndpointHttp"
              contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter"
    bindingConfiguration="customBindingNotSecure"/>

        </service>


    </services>
    <behaviors>

        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="CustomClientBehavior">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate>
                        <defaultCertificate findValue="serverx509v1" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                        <authentication customCertificateValidatorType="com.abodata.plat1.WCFProxy.PlatoneCertificateValidator, PlatoneWSRelay"
                         certificateValidationMode="Custom" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
                    </serviceCertificate>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>

        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="routingService">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <routing routeOnHeadersOnly="true" filterTableName="routingTable1" />
                <serviceCredentials>

                    <clientCertificate>

                        <authentication customCertificateValidatorType="com.abodata.plat1.WCFProxy.PlatoneCertificateValidator, PlatoneWSRelay"
                         certificateValidationMode="Custom" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
                    </clientCertificate>
                    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                     customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="com.abodata.plat1.WCFProxy.UsernameValidator, PlatoneWSRelay" />

                </serviceCredentials>

            </behavior>

            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>


        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <routing>
        <filters>
            <filter name="MatchAllFilter1" filterType="MatchAll" />
        </filters>
        <filterTables>
            <filterTable name="routingTable1">
                <add filterName="MatchAllFilter1" endpointName="PlatoneWSService" />
            </filterTable>
        </filterTables>

    </routing>

    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://10.0.2.243:9006/Persistence"
         binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="platoneBinding"
         contract="*" name="PlatoneWSService">

            <identity>
 <dns value="serverx509v1" />
</identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>


    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

EDIT: I managed to establish the TLS connection by adding to my configuration

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false"  checkCertificateRevocationList="false"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

But... now I have problems with the security header of my soap envelop. The client sends the message correctly to my router, but it removes the security header, so I get an exception...

Comment: Have you worked with secure WCF services before?

Comment: @Bernard What do you mean? I have another service which uses SSL, but I'm not an expert of WCF (this is the second time I use it).

Comment: That's what I meant; that is, whether you have worked with another SSL-enabled WCF service. Securing this "routing" service should work the same way.

Comment: I managed to establish the connection. But the problem now is the security header of the soap envelope. I can't preserve it. My router removes it, so I get back a security error

Comment: Ok.. I solved.. tomorrow morning i will post the answer with my working configuration (now I can't add an answer.. not enough reputation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok... I solved also the second problem.

My router binding must not specify the security tag, otherwise it process the envelop. 
This is my working configuration

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>



    <system.serviceModel>

        <bindings>
            <!-- Must use custom binding: silverlight only support basicHttpBinding that is not
                    SOAP 1.2. So.. I create a custom binding-->
            <customBinding>
                <!-- Security Off version-->
                <binding name="customBindingNotSecure">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10"/>
                    <httpTransport />
                </binding>

                <!-- Security On -->
                <binding name="customBindingSecure">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                    <httpsTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2000000" maxBufferSize="2000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" />
                </binding>

                <binding name="platoneBinding">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />                   
                    <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000" maxBufferPoolSize="1000000000" maxBufferSize="1000000000" />
                </binding>

            </customBinding>


        </bindings>

        <services>

            <service behaviorConfiguration="routingService" name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService">
                <endpoint address=""
                  binding="customBinding"
                  name="reqReplyEndpoint"
                  contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter"  bindingConfiguration="customBindingSecure"/>

                <endpoint address=""
                  binding="customBinding"
                  name="reqReplyEndpointHttp"
                  contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter"
        bindingConfiguration="customBindingNotSecure"/>

            </service>


        </services>
        <behaviors>

            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="routingService">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <routing routeOnHeadersOnly="true" filterTableName="routingTable1" />
                </behavior>

                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <routing>
            <filters>
                <filter name="MatchAllFilter1" filterType="MatchAll" />
            </filters>
            <filterTables>
                <filterTable name="routingTable1">
                    <add filterName="MatchAllFilter1" endpointName="PlatoneWSService" />
                </filterTable>
            </filterTables>

        </routing>

        <client>
            <!-- https://10.0.2.243:9006/Persistence -->
            <endpoint address="https://10.0.2.243:9006/Persistence"
             binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="platoneBinding"
             contract="*" name="PlatoneWSService">

            </endpoint>
        </client>


        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>


    <system.net>
        <settings>
            <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false"  checkCertificateRevocationList="false"/>
        </settings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Dimensions for the buffer and message have to be "tested" (that is.. I chose a big number to make it works...)